# Grails 3 change default service scope

Tags: grails, grails3

In grails 3, the default service scope is `Singleton`, the documents show it's easy to override this by defining

```
static scope='request'
```

in the service class.  Is it possible to change the default service scope for an application similar to the way it is done for controllers in `application.groovy`?

The specific issue is a Service class in a plugin is calling application services (which are designed around `request` scope).  This was working in grails 2, but with the upgrade to grails 3 it no longer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the default scope for an application similar
>   to the way it is done for controllers in application.groovy?

There is no direct support for that, no.  You could write a bean definition post processor that could impose that change.